# Difference between sc.broadcast and broadcast function in spark sql

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, broadcast

I have used `sc.broadcast` for lookup files to improve the performance.

I also came to know there is a function called `broadcast` in Spark SQL Functions.

What is the difference between two?

Which one i should use it for broadcasting the reference/look up tables?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to achieve broadcast join in Spark SQL you should use `broadcast` function (combined with desired `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` configuration). It will:

- Mark given relation for broadcasting.
- Adjust SQL execution plan.
- When output relation is evaluated it will take care of collecting data, and broadcasting, and applying correct join mechanism.

`SparkContext.broadcast` is used to handle local objects and is applicable for use with Spark `DataFrames`.

Answer (score 12):

one word answer :

1) `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast()` function  is user supplied,explicit hint for given sql join.

2) `sc.broadcast` is for broadcasting readonly shared variable.

---

#### More details about `broadcast` function #1 :

Here is scala doc from 
[`sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala)

which says.

> - Broadcast: if one side of the join has an estimated physical size that is smaller than the    *     user-configurable
>     [[SQLConf.AUTO_BROADCASTJOIN_THRESHOLD]] threshold    *     or if that
>     side has an explicit broadcast hint (e.g. the user applied the    *
>     [[org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast()]] function to a
>     DataFrame), then that side    *     of the join will be broadcasted
>     and the other side will be streamed, with no shuffling    *
>     performed. If both sides of the join are eligible to be broadcasted
>     then the    *
> - Shuffle hash join: if the average size of a single
>     partition is small enough to build a hash    *     table.
> - Sort merge: if the matching join keys are sortable.
> - If there is no joining keys, Join implementations are chosen with the following precedence:
>
>   - BroadcastNestedLoopJoin: if one side of the join could be broadcasted
>   - CartesianProduct: for Inner join
>   - BroadcastNestedLoopJoin

- The below method controls the behavior based on size we set to 
  `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` by default it is 10mb

> Note : `smallDataFrame.join(largeDataFrame)` does not do a broadcast hash join, but `largeDataFrame.join(smallDataFrame)` does.

```
/** Matches a plan whose output should be small enough to be used in broadcast join.
         **/
        private def canBroadcast(plan: LogicalPlan): Boolean = {
          plan.statistics.isBroadcastable ||
            plan.statistics.sizeInBytes <= conf.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold
        }
```

In future the [below configurations will be deprecated in coming versions of spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html).
[image]

Comment: @BdEngineer : broadcast variable is to read the data from local variables not a distributed structure like dataset/dataframe. is what jacek is saying. which is 100% correct