# NullPointer in broadcast value being passed as parameter

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

:)

I'd like to say that I'm new in Spark, as many of these posts start..but the truth is I'm not that new.
Still, I'm facing this issue with broadcast variables.

When a variable is broadcast, each executor receives a copy of it. Later on, when this variable is referenced in the part of the code that is executed in the executors (let's say map or foreach), if the variable reference that was set in the driver is not passed to it, the executor does not know what are we talking about. Which I think is perfectly explain [here](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Why-I-can-t-use-broadcast-var-defined-in-a-global-object-td27523.html)

My problem is I am getting a nullPointerException even tough I passed the broadcast reference to the executors.

```
class A {
    var broadcastVal: Broadcast[Dataframe] = _
    ...

    def method1 {
        broadcastVal = otherMethodWhichSendBroadcast
        doSomething(broadcastVal, others)
    }
}

class B {
    def doSomething(...) {
        forEachPartition {x => doSomethingElse(x, broadcasVal)}
    }
}

object C {
    def doSomethingElse(...) {
        broadcastVal.value.show --> Exception
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***RDD and DataFrames are already distributed structures, no need to broadcast them as local variable .(`org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast()` function (which is used while doing joins) is not local variable broadcast )***

---

Even if you try the code syntax wise it wont show any compilation error, rather it will throw `RuntimeException` like `NullPointerException` which is **100% valid.**

Example to Explain the behavior :

```
package examples

import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

object BroadCastCheck extends App {
  org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName(getClass.getName).master("local").getOrCreate()
  val sc = spark.sparkContext
  val df = spark.range(100).toDF()
  var broadcastVal: Broadcast[DataFrame] = sc.broadcast(df)


  val t1 = sc.parallelize(0 until 10)
  val t2 = sc.broadcast(2) // this is right since its local variable can be primitive or map or any scala collection
  val t3 = t1.filter(_ % t2.value == 0).persist() //this is the way of ha
  t3.foreach {
    x =>
      println(x)
      // broadcastVal.value.toDF().show // null pointer  wrong way
    //   spark.range(100).toDF().show // null pointer  wrong way

  }
}
```

Result : (if you un comment `broadcastVal.value.toDF().show` or `spark.range(100).toDF().show` in above code)

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.sparkContext(SparkPlan.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.metrics$lzycompute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:528)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.metrics(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:527)
```

Further [read the difference between broadcast variable and broadcast function here...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40363613/647053)

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly! I see it now, makes sense completly #facePalmEmoji the reason why I was trying to broadcast a DF was because I wanted each executor to have it (whole) in memory and thus avoid asking the driver or another executor. It is a streaming application and latencies are very important. But I think then it is better to do a collect of the df, since it is small, and broadcast as MapObject. Do you think there is a better way?

Comment: if its small/tiny dataframe with  few number of records then it its ok to `collect` and broadcast as local variable. other wise you will get Out of memory exceptions. since collect will move whole data to driver...  there are some other techniques based on requirements. One way is cache `df.cache` will cache in the memory. you can use a join (with largedf.join(broadcast(smalldf),Seq(keys to match for join )) on cached dataframe.  to lookup data. it works in spark core as well as spark streaming.